# image icons added are lost after updating to iOS 12 in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

In my app, I am displaying image having a photo at the centre of the container and added the image button at the top of a container. It was working fine. But some of my users updated to iOS 12 and the image icons added at the top are no longer present.

```
class Screen extends Form{
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 this.getTitleArea().setPreferredH(0);
//photoContainer, where image is placed as imageViewer
 Container photoContainer= buildPreviewPane();
 addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, photoContainer);
 buildCommandBar();

  }

  protected Container buildPreviewPane()    {
    Container cont = new Container();   
    cont.setLayout (new BorderLayout());
    getStyle().setMargin(0,  0, 0, 0);
    getStyle().setPadding(0,  0, 0, 0);
    cont.addComponent (BorderLayout.CENTER, new Label("  "));

    return cont;
}

protected void buildCommandBar(){
Container c = new Container();
c.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
c.getStyle().setPadding(Component.TOP, 40);


    int size = Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(4,  false);
    if (Display.getInstance().isTablet()) {
        size *= 2;
    }

    Button deleteCommand = new Button();
        try {
            Image im = Image.createImage("/Delete-64-lygrey.png").scaled(size - 2, size - 2);
            deleteCommand.setIcon(im);
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
        c.addComponent(deleteCommand);

    Button okCommand = new Button();
    try {
        Image im = Image.createImage("/Checked-64-ltgrey.png").scaled(size - 2, size - 2);
        okCommand.setIcon(im);
    }catch (Exception e){}
    c.addComponent(okCommand);

    addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH, c);

}
```

So, the two commands/ button (delete and ok) are added at the north of component. And these buttons are invisible after updating to iOS 12. I have been using from years, and working fine till now, some of my clients got this issue when they upgraded to iOS 12. Works fine on iOS 11.4.1. So, from the first image those are the icons that were visible or present in that form, second depicts the form when iOS 12 installed, icons are lost, and only one icon is present, and if you revisit that form again and again, sometimes all icons are lost.
So, anything that broke out? Any help will be very helpful.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I suggest following Steve's suggestions here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2553